# Webscrape - R - Extract from complex page

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

i need to extract values for 80 cities from this page:

https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/senioren/

Unfortunately, the URL does not include the names of the cities, instead it has endings as follows: "district/05754.

If it would have names, I would have used:

```
ds= list ("Munich","Cologne", "further cities...")

for (city in ds){
  page = paste0("https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/senioren/" 

...}
```

What would you do in that case? You could type in the city/postal code on this page - https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/senioren/ - but I do not know how to code that so it does that automatically in a for-loop.

Further, I want to extract the rank for the variable "Verkehrssicherheit for each city under "Sicherheit und Infrastruktur". I tried it with Selectorgadget but its problematic. Any tips?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names and codes could be pulled from an svg file. You could then construct a mapping table to assist you with the ids from the names:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
 
lookup <- read_html("https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/dmap.svg") %>%
  html_nodes("#kreise path") %>%
  map_df(., function(x) {
    data.frame(
      place = x %>% html_attr("data-name"),
      id = x %>% html_attr("id")
    )
  })

urls <- paste0('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/senioren/', lookup$id)
```

---

However, you can get names, ranks etc as json as follows:

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')
```

You could manipulate the json data e.g. to have the ascending ranking by location:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts

df <- map_df(data, function(x) {
  data.frame(
    name = x %>% {.$name},
    rank = x %>% {.$overall$rank}
  )
})

df <- df[order(df$rank),]
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! I am trying to figure out, how you found the data of the page? ("https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json" as well as "https://deutschland-studie-senioren-familie.zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/dmap.svg") It would be great if you could tell me, how to access those. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I used the network tab. If you press F12 in chrome to open dev tools and go to network tab, then press F5 to refresh your target webpage you will see those requests appear in the xhr section of the tab.

Comment: Do you prefer to search in the xhr section? Do you specifically search for .json and .sng data in there? In which cases do you think, should I execute the data extraction to your method above? Thank you very much for all your answers, I already enjoyed learning from you. :)

Comment: I look in the xhr section because with dynamic pages (which many modern pages are) - the website often makes additional xhr requests to update content .e.g. as with this page. I didn't need to search in this case as they were the only 2 xhr. If you go to my profile page there is a section of links I commonly share and within that there are links to how to find xhr requests.

Comment: I understood. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @QHarr, i want to extract specific rankings/numbers of only some districts ( i have a list of districts "01000" etc.) out of the json data (data <- jsonlite::read_json('...zdf.de/assets/data/senioren/districts.json')$districts). I am struggling with the syntax. Could u help?

Comment: filter the dataframe with a mask for only the items of interest?

Comment: like I did below (new comment under this post)?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question and show what you are trying to achieve. Looks like people will downvote for asking a question where an answer should go.